# TensorFlow ver1.x CNNによる文字認識について

Tags: tensorflow

「TensorFlow&Kerasプログラミング実装ハンドブック」を参考に、TensorFlowでmnistの手書き数字を用いてCNNによる文字認識を実装しようとしました。
しかし、認識精度が何度やっても0.1になってしまいます。おそらく予測の値が全て同じ数字になってしまっている(全て1と予想したり、全て7と予想している)ことが原因だと思いますが、どうしてそうなってしまうのかが分かりません。
以下コードです。

```
#データフローグラフ
#学習率とエポック数を設定
learning_rate = 0.01  #学習率
epochs = 1500         #学習を繰り返す回数
batch_size = 50      #ミニバッチのサイズ
dropout = 0.5         #非ドロップアウト率

#MNISTからデータを取得
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images.reshape(60000, 784)/255
test_images = test_images.reshape(10000, 784)/255
to_categorical = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical
train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

#入力層
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None, 784])
#画像データの二次元配列[データ数×784]を
#[データ数×28×28×1]の4次元配列に変換
out_img = tf.reshape(x,[-1, 28, 28, 1])

#第1層 : 畳み込み層
#2次元フィルター(3×3を32枚)
f1 = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 1, 32],stddev = 0.1))
#畳み込みを行うopノード
conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(out_img, f1, strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')
#フィルターのバイアス
b1 = tf.Variable(
    tf.constant(0.1,shape=[32]))
#活性化関数はReLU
#出力 : (画像の枚数, 28, 28, 32)
out_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1 + b1)

#第2層 : プーリング層
#最大プーリングを適用
out_pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(
    out_conv1,
    ksize=[1,2,2,1],
    strides=[1,2,2,1],
    padding='SAME')

#第3層 : 畳み込み層
f2 = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 32, 64],stddev = 0.1))
#畳み込みを行うopノード
conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(out_pool1, f2, strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')
#フィルターのバイアス
b2 = tf.Variable(
    tf.constant(0.1,shape=[64]))
#活性化関数はReLU
#出力 : (画像の枚数, 28, 28, 32)
out_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2 + b2)

#第4層 : プーリング層
#最大プーリングを適用
out_pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(
    out_conv2,
    ksize=[1,2,2,1],
    strides=[1,2,2,1],
    padding='SAME')

#ドロップアウト
#非ドロップアウト率を保持するプレースホルダー
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
#ドロップアウトを行うopノード
out_drop = tf.nn.dropout(out_pool2, 1-keep_prob)

#Flatten
out_flat = tf.reshape(out_drop,[-1, 7*7*64])

#第5層 : 全結合層
#重み
w_comb1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([7*7*64,1024],stddev=0.1))
#バイアス
b_comb1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[1024]))
#活性化関数
out_comb1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(out_flat,w_comb1)+b_comb1)

#第6層 : 出力層
#重み
w_comb2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1024, 10],stddev=0.1))
#バイアス
b_comb2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[10]))
#活性化関数
out = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(out_comb1,w_comb2)+b_comb2)

#正解データの型を定義
#誤差関数
t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
loss = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(t*tf.log(out), axis=[1]))

#ミニマイザー
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(
    learning_rate).minimize(loss)

#評価
correct = tf.equal(
    tf.argmax(out, 1),tf.argmax(t, 1)
    )
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

#変数を初期化するノード
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

```
#セッション部分
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    for i in range(epochs):
        #ミニバッチを抽出
        #オフセット=回数×バッチサイズを訓練データの行数で割った余り
        offset = (i * batch_size) % 60000
        #オフセットの位置からミニバッチを抽出
        batch_train_images = train_images[
            offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        batch_train_labels= train_labels[
            offset:(offset + batch_size),:]
        sess.run(train_op,
                    feed_dict={x:batch_train_images,
                    t:batch_train_labels,
                    keep_prob:dropout})
            #100回ごとにテストデータを使用して精度を出力
        if (i+1) % 100 == 0:
            acc_val = sess.run(accuracy,
                                  feed_dict={x:test_images,
                                     t:test_labels,
                                     keep_prob:1})
            print('Step %d: accuracy = %.2f' % (i+1, acc_val))
```

以下出力結果です

```
Step 200: accuracy = 0.10
Step 300: accuracy = 0.10
Step 400: accuracy = 0.10
Step 500: accuracy = 0.10
Step 600: accuracy = 0.10
Step 700: accuracy = 0.10
Step 800: accuracy = 0.10
Step 900: accuracy = 0.10
Step 1000: accuracy = 0.10
Step 1100: accuracy = 0.10
Step 1200: accuracy = 0.10
Step 1300: accuracy = 0.10
Step 1400: accuracy = 0.10
Step 1500: accuracy = 0.10
```

古いバージョンのTensorFlowで申し訳ないのですが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: お使いのバージョンは何でしょうか？

Comment: Tensorflowのバージョンのことでしたら、TesorFlow2を使っていますが

Comment: import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()

Comment: というコードでver1.xの振る舞いをするようにしています